# how to insert autoincrement number with my mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am newbie to mongoose, I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    seq: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    firstname: {
        type: String
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String
    },
    dob: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    displayname: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: String
    },
    profilePic: {
        type: String
    },
    city: {
        type: String
    },
    gender: {
        type: String
    },
    profileType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profileId: {
        type: String
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Number
    },
    ageVerified: {
        type: String
    },
    ipAddress: {
        type: String
    },
    key: {
        type: String
    },
    osType: {
        type: String
    },
    osVersion: {
        type: String
    },
    deviceName: {
        type: String
    },
    joinedDate: {
        type: String
    },
    connectedAccounts: [{
        profileType: {
            type: String
        },
        profileId: {
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        }
    }]
}, {collection: 'user'});
```

Please note the userID is an auto increment number field, for inserting value am using the mongoose query like:

```
new user(contents).save(function (err,doc){};
```

'contents' is a object, which contain data for all the field except userID, here my question is how to insert value for the userID(autoincrement number) while inserting records for other fields? And I refer this [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)to set the auto increment value... But I don't know how to use this in mongoose?

Comment: or if we can add an autoincrement number into mongodb while new record is adding? is possible?

Comment: Your userID is not a number but a string. And you have the whole article here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Why do you *need* this auto-incrementing field? Mongo gives you a unique identifier in the `_id` field. Does this not suffice?

Answer (score 8):

Following the MongoDB tutorial, **[Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)**, you need to first create a separate `counters` collection to track the last number sequence used. The `_id` field contains the sequence name i.e. the `userID` field in the user collection and the `seq` field contains the last value of the sequence.

To start with, insert into the counters collection the initial value for the `userID`:

```
db.counter.insert(
   {
      "_id": "userID",
      "seq": 0
   }
)
```

Having populated the counters collection, generate its schema in Mongoose:

```
var counterSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "_id": { "type": String, "required": true },
    "seq": { "type": Number, "default": 0 }
});

var counter = mongoose.model('counter', counterSchema);
```

Then redefine your user schema so that when you save a user model it first calls the counter model's `findByIdAndUpdate()` method to atomically increment the seq value and return this new value which can then be used as the next `userID` value:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "userID": { "type": String, "required": true },
    "firstname": { "type": String },
    "lastname": { "type": String },
    // other properties ...
    }, { "collection": "user" }
);

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    var doc = this;
    counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { "_id": "userID" }, 
        { "$inc": { "seq": 1 } }
    , function(error, counter)   {
        if(error) return next(error);
        doc.userID = counter.seq.toString();
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the post..! while execute it throws error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seq' of null" at "doc.userID = counter.seq.toString();"

Comment: @Karthik Did you first insert into the `counters` collection the initial value for the `userID` before attempting to save the `user` model?

Comment: did u mentioning that, i have to insert a row in "counters" collections in mongodb

Comment: @Karthik You have to create the collection first, I even explicitly mentioned that in my answer _To start with, insert into the counters collection the initial value for the userID:_

Comment: i have created a counter collection with initial values like {"_id":"500",seq:0}. still it is throwing the same error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seq' of null" at "doc.userID = counter.seq.toString();"

Comment: "please ignore previous comment" yes i created the collection like {"userID":"500","seq":0} but now the error seems like : { [ValidationError: user validation failed]
  message: 'user validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { userID: 
      { [ValidatorError: Path `userID` is required.]
        properties: [Object],
        message: 'Path `userID` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'userID',
        value: undefined } } }

Comment: i did n't passed a value to the userID so the validation error has thrown. if i passed any value to the userID it throws the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seq' of null" at "doc.userID = counter.seq.toString();"

Comment: The counter collection should only have one document with an `_id` value of the string `"userID"`, nothing else. You are getting the errors since you have done it differently, not what's specified in the answer. I would suggest you drop the `counters` collection since you created a new column `"userID"` with a value 500 which generated a new `_id`, and repopulate it with just one document, i.e. `{
      "_id": "userID",
      "seq": 0
   }` as is, then save the user data.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an autoincrement prop based on the length of your collection, you can do something like this:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    this.constructor.find({}).then((users) => {
      this.autoIncrementProp = users.length + 1;
      next();
    });
  }
});
```

**isNew** is a reserved Schema name (*Boolean flag specifying if the document is new.*)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the logic of `schema.findByIdAndUpdate` is "return the current value and THEN increment it", you can also use @chridam's solution with the following edit:

```
var counter = mongoose.model('counter', counterSchema);


userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  var doc = this;
  counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { "_id": "userID" }, 
      { "$inc": { "seq": 1 } }
  , function(error, c /*counter*/)   {
      if(error)
        return next(error);
      else if(!c) {
        c = new counter({ _id: "userID" }, { $inc: { seq: 1 } };
        c.save(function() {
          doc.userID = (c.seq - 1) + '';
          next();
        });
      } else {
        doc.userID = counter.seq.toString();
        next();
      }
  });
});
```

Please, note that this solutions makes your code function from scratch WITHOUT forcing you to initialize the DB.

The tricks lies in the first round of the loop. `counter` is undefined, so you need to initialize it, but if you initialize it equal to 0, next tick the code tries to assign `userID=0` again!

This is because on one hand there is the logic of `schema.findByIdAndUpdate` that reads-first the value and then increments it, on the other hand you need a logic that assigns-first the value though.

You can join these two logics by making the algorithm skip the first step and setting variable values as above.

Notes: `counterSchema` is the same as chridam's:

```
counterSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "seq": { "type": Number, "default": 0 }
});
```

Comment: That's good, I have been looking for something like this, but am thinking of what if a user is to be deleted, will the userId readjust to still follow it's normal numbering order . e.g if we have 123, and 2 was deleted, will 3 come to be 2.

Comment: Unfortunately counters does not fill empty gaps. If such behaviour you describe happens frequently, the system tends to have several gaps.