# How to save a document's index with mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose

I have a mongoDB collection with 200 documents called Games. Each document has a bunch of information about an instance of a game. I would like to append the index of the game onto the model/document such that I can create an endpoint that can retrieve a game simply by its number or index. For example

localhost:3000/api/game/150

where 150 would be the 150th game in the collection.

How do I index already existing games, and how do I save the index of new games when saving a document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert autoincrement number with my mongoose collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786217/how-to-insert-autoincrement-number-with-my-mongoose-collection)

Comment: I think the answer to this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786217/how-to-insert-autoincrement-number-with-my-mongoose-collection