# MongoDB Auto increment as ID for new users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a small Web-API project using MongoDB.
As far as I know, MongoDB uses _id:UnixDateETC but I want a ID that like in MySQL or MSQL is able to autoincrement each time a new user is created.
I played around with the "find().count()", found some attemps on the internet, but none of what I tried seem to work. I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it wrong or if it's not possible by doing such thing like I tried them. ( My attempt can be found under "models/user.js":id)

Any suggestions how I directly can go into the schema, count it's entries and than add it to the new record without any complicated new seperate function ? The reason for that is that I'm trying to hold the models clean/readable.

Thanks in advance.

**routes/user.js:**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let User = require('../models/user');
var config = require('../configs/config');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


function userRegistration(req, res) {
    var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.psw, 10);
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.psw = hashedPassword;
        user.save(function (err) {      
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem registering the user.");
            var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.userName }, config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
            });
                  res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });        
  });
}

//export all the functions
module.exports = { userRegistration };
```

**models/user.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: this.db.id.find().count() + 1,
    userName: String,
    psw: String,
    email: String , 
    active : Boolean
});




module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/34786217/122005

Comment: you have to change the id value in preSave event

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The comment to look at the preSave and the link with an example was just what I needed. Had some troubles, but got it to work after playing with it for some hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work.

What I had to do was to create a preSave in my **"/models/user.js"**

**model/user.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    userName: String,
    psw: String,
    email: String , 
    active : Boolean
});


UserSchema.pre("save", function(next){
    var docs = this;
    mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).countDocuments(function(error, counter){
        if(error) return next(error);
        docs.id = counter+1;
        next();
    });   
});
```

**##Edit 02.07.2021:**
Note that this solution only works aslong u clear or keep instead of deleting your document(s). Otherwise u will end up with duplicate ID's since I count the number of currently existing documents.
Back then my final solution was to store a counter/value in another collection/table and increment it each time a new document gets created to keep track of my id(s). This newly incremented value will then be used in our preSave instead of counting documents...

Comment: If you delete 20 documents from your collection, wouldn`t this create duplicate id fields?

Comment: @CaioCésarS.Leonardi Sadly I don't have the code anymore for this project. But yes, as you said before u will end up with duplicate entries if u just count the documents. So the final solution I ended up some weeks after (Ended up in the situation with duplicates) was to store the value or in other words a counter in another collection/table that gets incremented by one each time a new document gets created. By that u will prevent to get the same id twice, since u will use the newly incremented value. There are probably other ways, but thats what I ended up with back then.